# Non-injective functions f(x) where f(f(f(x)))=f(x) but is not an involution

Tags: functions

I assumed that for $f: R \to R$ if $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)$ then $f$ is an involution, i.e. $f=f^{-1}$. But I'm told that $f$ must be injective for that to be true.

Thus I'm seeking non-injective functions that fulfills $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)$ but $f(f(x)) \neq x$.

Functions I've found so far are piecewise functions such that for each sub-function $f_s$ its interval $I$, $x \in I \to f_s(x) \in I$. Some examples are the constant function $f(x)=c$, $sign(x)$, and
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2x, & x \le -2 \\ 0, & -2 < x \le 10 \\ 3x, & 10<x \end{cases}$$

I'm unable to prove or disprove it though, so that would be great help.

Comment: I guess you rather want $f(f(f(x))=f(x)$ but $f(f(x)) \neq x$ ??

Comment: @TheSilverDoe yeah

Comment: What are you asking for if you already have examples?

Comment: @Sil whether there are more examples beyond those described or some proof those are the only examples

Comment: Just to make sure, you are not asking if these three functions are all they are, you are asking if there is example that cannot be written as a piecewise function such that $x \in I \to f_s(x) \in I$ for each of the piecewise interval $I$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This relationship is fulfilled by any idempotent function, as they are defined by $f(f(x))=f(x)$, and therefore also fulfill your requirement. The most typical examples of idempotent functions are projections. Although you can construct a bunch of examples by picking any non-empty $A\subseteq \Bbb R$, and requiring

- The image of $f$ is contained in $A$
- $f$ restricted to $A$ is the identity

(This is actually fulfilled by *any* idempotent function, so this will let you construct *all* the examples. So even though this isn't the actual definition, thinking about it this way makes it easier to construct examples than thinking about it as $f(f(x))=f(x)$.)

You can loosen the second requirement here and still fulfill your requirement. Instead of requiring $f$ to be the identity on $A$, we can require it to be an involution on $A$.

For instance, the function
$$
f(x)=\cases{1& if $x<-1$\\-x& if $-1\leq x\leq 1$\\-1& if $1<x$}
$$
is an involution on $[-1,1]$, and $[-1,1]$ contains the entire image of $f$. So it will fulfill $f(f(f(x)))=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to understand this is that such an $f$ is an involution on its image. If $y$ is in the image then it is of the form $f(x)$ for some $x$, so $ff(y)=fff(x)=f(x)=y$.

However, the image might not be the whole set you are working on. For any $x$ not in the image, $f$ must send that $x$ to somewhere in the image, ending up non-injective in the process. Since $x$ is not in the image it cannot be the case that $ff(x)=x$.

In fact, this provides a algorithm for constructing every possible function satisfying what you want.

- First, pick a subset $A \subset R$ to be the image of $f$.
- Pick any involution of that subset $A$.
- For the rest of $R$, map it into $A$ by any method you choose.

Any function you construct this way will be what you require.

For the functions you gave as examples.

- $f(x)= c$: The image is just a singleton, with the identity on that singleton and everything else mapped to that singleton.
- $sign(x)$: The image is $\{-1,0,1\}$, with the identity on that three elements. Note that this suggests that $-sign(x)$ also works, using the involution that swaps $-1$ and $1$.
- Piecewise linear functions. From the way you described it, I'm wondering if the only piecewise functions you considered are either the identity on each interval or the reverse direction, either of which would be an involution. Note that this won't work for other such functions unless you check some other way that these form an involution.
- The final function. This does not satisfy the condition. On $y \leq -4$, all contained within the image, this acts as $f(y) = 2y$ which is not an involution, so the entire function can't satisfy your condition.